# Detect language by text in Java

Tags: java

How to find the language of an input string. For example:
getLanguage("Hello world") - return en.
getLanguage("Hola Mundo") - return es

I know it might not be accurate in 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lingua to do it.

1. Add to maven:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.pemistahl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lingua</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

2. In Java:

```
    import com.github.pemistahl.lingua.api.*;
    import static com.github.pemistahl.lingua.api.Language.*;
    
    public class TextToLang {
        public String getLanguage(String text)
        {

            final LanguageDetector detector = LanguageDetectorBuilder.fromLanguages(ENGLISH, FRENCH, GERMAN, SPANISH).withMinimumRelativeDistance(0.1).build();
            final Language detectedLanguage = detector.detectLanguageOf(text);
            return detectedLanguage.name();
        }
    }
```